# Windows Command Line 'Start' prevents finding all files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In a batch file, I have this line that runs an antivirus program.  I'd like to ensure that it finishes its job before the batch moves on the following lines.  From what I understand, START/WAIT is the wait to go.  Unfortunately, START/WAIT breaks the line of code.

Here is the code that runs:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Anti-Virus\" d:\files\%1\ProcessFiles\%2-proc\*.*
```

This code does not run:

```
START/WAIT "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anti-Virus\fsav" d:\files\%1\ProcessFiles\%2-proc\*.*
```

When this line runs, I get an error saying:

```
"Windows cannot find 'd:\files\abc\ProcessFiles\abc-proc\*.*'. 
Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."
```

While that error prompt is open, if I navigate to that folder, there ARE files in there.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what is the program you are trying to run? `C:\Program Files (x86)\Anti-Virus\ ` seems to be a folder, not a program, and if we take that as a title, then `d:\files\%1\ProcessFiles\%2-proc\*.*` seems to be multiple files, not a single program

Comment: Apologies, I obfuscated too much.  In my code, that line reads "C:\Program Files (x86)\F-Secure\Anti-Virus\fsav".  I never know how much or little real info to remove from my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using hint from [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html),
Always include a **TITLE** this can be a simple string like "My Script" or just a pair of empty quotes ""
According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but you <strike>may</strike> will have problems if it is omitted.

`START "" /WAIT "C:\Your Anti-Virus\antivir" "d:\files\%1\ProcessFiles\%2-proc\*.*`

Answer (score 1):

`START/WAIT` is not a single word, it's two seperated by a space.
Also, putting double-quotes around the file-specs will help if any have spaces in their names.

Try This:

```
START /WAIT "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anti-Virus\fsav" "d:\files\%1\ProcessFiles\%2-proc\*.*"
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think I saw else where when researching this problem that putting `*.*` in quotes would keep it from working as expected.  Meaning, it would no longer list all files.  Is that not the case?

Comment: @Tyson: I've never run into that problem, and it's necessary when using a path with spaces in it.

Comment: @Tyson `CD` to a directory with many files and type this at the command prompt: `for %x in ("*.*") do set /a count=count+1`, then do a `DIR` and compare the numbers.